# Tracking changes with Word Online

Tags: word-online

I am doing consulting work proofreading documents. The documents are accessible via a Sharepoint server and I can edit them with Office 365. I'm supposed to edit them with track changes turned on and leave comments. I know how to do both with an installed version of Office. I'd like to be able to do both with the online version of Word.

I figured out how to create and view comments. However, I don't see where I can turn on track changes.